# Copy SQL DB files/backups

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

We have a task to copy 2TB of DB files/backups over LAN in a most efficient and speedy way. We are brainstorming amongst our team to come up with a best solution.

These files are multiple backups and compression is already used.

Can someone advise the best way to do this?

Comment: Is that 2TB after using SQL server backup compression feature? Just wandering!

Comment: If you have backup to transfer which is 2TB in size best I can think of is dump the contents of backup on tape and FEDEX it to destination. I dont think you can transfer 2 TB backup without any issue over network.

Comment: Yes. Backups are compressed. Just to clarify it is not a single backup file. There are multiple backup files for different DBs. There combined size is 2TB.

Comment: You ZIP it and transfer it over network then make sure you do not put much load on network and inform network team before you do it. Apart from this I am not sure there can be any other good way.

Comment: Normal copy or robocoy which one would be better?

Comment: robocopy would be faster on newer versions of window like 2008 r2 ,2012

Comment: @Shanky Zipping a compressed SQL Server backup file will not reduce its  size significantly. Also it will increase the restore time, which might not be acceptable according to the RTO.

Comment: Just another option, are the servers physically located near each other?  Might be easier to strap on a USB3.0 drive and just move it around that way.  Doing so, you eliminate the load on the network and you can do a straight restore from the USB3.0 drive on the destination server.  This only works if the servers are physically near each other, though.

Comment: Thanks Kris Gruttemeyer! Unfortunately, they are far from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend to use Robocopy, it has the support of multi threaded copy. And it won't take ages to calculate the packages before.

Your syntax would be as follows:

robocopy "C:\SOURCE\Folder\folder" "D:\folder\destination" /mir /MT:XX

I use the mir option, since it will copy everything, meaning doing a perfect mirror. So you don't have to worry if your copy job stucks for any reason. You can easily run the same command again and it will only copy the missing files.
Be careful if you have hidden files in your folder, for example if you have the files placed directly on your Drive root folder. Than you will have problems copying the recycler ;)

MT Parameter
The Command /MT will run your copies with multiple threads. You can choose a number between 1 and 128, default is 8.
Please read : [msdn Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Also one advice is to copy from the machine with more CPU Power since a copy job will alwas run on the CPU where you are currently logged in. In most cases I copy from the destination server, since it is probably not in use so far.